# How to add string in the middle of a url that's in a txt file

Tags: python

I have a text file with a few urls,
they all lead to an html pop up log in so I can't inspect element and have it sign in, since im using:

```
username = abc
password = abc

fp = open('ALLURLS.txt')
for line in fp.readlines():
    print(line)
    url = (line)

    driver = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver")
    driver.get(url)
```

how can I get it to insert "username:password@" in the middle of the URL from the text file.

PYTHON PLEASE

Comment: Select the index, then slice it: ```str[:index]+new_str+str[index:]```

Comment: lets say the link is https:// facebook.com, how would I do that? Sorry, fairly new to python

Comment: it depends where you want to insert the new string

Comment: lets say "https:// (insert the "username:password@" string here) facebook.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need simple string formatting,

```
username = "abc"
password = 123

fp = open("ALLURLS.txt")
for url in fp.readlines():
    # Let's take the url as "https://stackoverflow.com"
    # and we want something like "https://abc:123@stackoverflow.com"
    index = 8 # index no. after "https://"
    url = url[:index] + f"{username}:{password}@" + url[index:]

    driver = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver")
    driver.get(url)
```

I Hope this is what you want. If not, please give an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

1. Slice the string from the start to a index
2. Add the formatted string
3. Slice the string from the index to the end

Also, note the function of `+` here. For numbers, it adds and for strings, it **concatenates** or combines.

Example

```
string1='https://facebook.com/'
index=8
username='1234'
password='abcd'
string2=string1[:index]+f'{username}:{password}@'+string1[index:]
print(string2)
```